# groupby mean of datetime64[ns] column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a datafrmame:

- user_id          object
- local time       datetime64[ns]
- value            int32

```py
  user_id          local time  value
0   user1 2023-01-01 00:00:00      3
1   user1 2023-01-01 00:00:00      3
2   user1 2023-01-01 01:00:00      7
3   user1 2023-01-01 01:00:00      2
4   user2 2023-01-01 02:00:00      4
5   user2 2023-01-01 02:00:00     10
6   user2 2023-01-01 03:00:00      7
7   user2 2023-01-01 03:00:00      2
```

I want to:

- groupby user_id
- mean of cols: "local time" (only time HH:MM:SS, not datetime)  and "value"

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(123)
# Define the number of users and values
num_users = 2
num_values = 4

# Generate the user IDs
user_ids = ['user{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(num_users)]

# Generate the local time values
local_time = pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01 00:00:00', periods=num_values, freq='H')

# Generate the random values
values = np.random.randint(1, 11, size=(num_values*num_users))

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'user_id': np.repeat(user_ids, num_values),
    'local time': np.repeat(local_time, num_users),
    'value': values})


# calculate the mean of local time TIME - NOT datetime.
print (df)

print("expected_output")


'''
      local time  value 
user1 00:30:00    3.75
user2 02:30:00   5.75
'''
df.groupby('user_id').mean()
```

## Expected Output:

I want the mena of the time (hour minutes and seoncds, not date) and mean of value, groupby user

```py
      local time  value 
user1 00:30:00    3.75
user2 02:30:00   5.75
```

Comment: In fact, I don't know what you expect :)

Comment: you can have a mean for duration values....what exactly is the "mean" of timestamps?

Comment: @mrxra I made a mistake in my example, i want the mean of the TIME, not of datetime only (so Hour, minute, second)

Comment: @Leo Providing desired output will clear all

Comment: @PandaKim I have modified the question and provided expected output: 

in summary groupby userid, and mean of the Time. so 10:30 am and 8:30am would give 9:30 am

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mean` compute only numeric by default. Use `numeric_only=False` to compute the mean of local time:

However you can use:

```
>>> df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False).mean(numeric_only=False)

  user_id          local time  value
0   user1 2023-01-01 09:36:00    3.8
1   user2 2023-01-03 00:00:00    4.4
2   user3 2023-01-04 14:24:00    5.2
```

**Update**

> I want the mean of Time, not dateime (so just hour, minute, seconds)

```
mean_time = lambda x: str(pd.to_timedelta(x.dt.time.astype(str)).mean())[7:]

out = (df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False)
         .agg({'local time': mean_time, 'value': 'mean'}))

  user_id local time  value
0   user1   00:30:00   3.75
1   user2   02:30:00   5.75
```

Comment: ah sorry i was unclear, in my example i made a mistake, i want the mean of Time, not dateime (so just hour, minute, seconds)

Comment: You have only the date part on your example?

Comment: yeah sorry, let me modify

Comment: @Correlien thanks! i wonder why there is no python function for this, it seems so useful (like to calcualte average time user goes to sleep)

Comment: The right way will be: `df['local time'].sub(df['local time'].dt.normalize()).mean()` but it does not change the problem to remove the '0 days' part.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data = {'user_id': {0: 'user1', 1: 'user1', 2: 'user1', 3: 'user1', 
                    4: 'user2', 5: 'user2', 6: 'user2', 7: 'user2'}, 
        'local time': {0: '2023-01-01 00:00:00', 1: '2023-01-01 00:00:00', 
                       2: '2023-01-01 01:00:00', 3: '2023-01-01 01:00:00', 
                       4: '2023-01-01 02:00:00', 5: '2023-01-01 02:00:00', 
                       6: '2023-01-01 03:00:00', 7: '2023-01-01 03:00:00'}, 
        'value': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 7, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 10, 6: 7, 7: 2}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['local time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['local time'])
```

**Code**

```
out = (df
       .groupby('user_id').mean(numeric_only=False)
       .assign(**{'local time' : lambda x: x['local time'].dt.time}))
```

`out`:

```
        local time  value
user_id     
user1   00:30:00    3.75
user2   02:30:00    5.75
```

`out.dtypes`

```
local time     object
value         float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi. Are you sure it works if the date part is not the same day? I mean `pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 03:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-02 03:00:00')]).mean().time()` should be `datetime.time(3, 0)` and not `datetime.time(15, 0)`?